# как повесить событие на часть элемента? Элемент Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Есть элемент canvas, нужно чтобы событие клика отрабатывало только в одной части этого элемента. Подскажите идеи, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вешаешь обработчик onclick, в теле обработчика ссылаешься на координаты места клика clientX  и clientY, дальше делаешь какие угодно математические сравнения